# How to escape \r\n in the body of a POST in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a JSON response as follows,

`{
    "name":"John Smith",
    "address": "#123\r\nRenault Road\r\n123456\r\n"
}`

and I need to extract the address and put it into my next POST request. I use the JSON Extractor as a post processing element and with `$..address` I set the extracted address to the variable `address`.

In my next request, I use the following as the POST data,

`{
    "id": "123456",
    "address": "${address}"
}`

So when I make the request I see the POST data as,

`{
    "id": "123456",
    "address": "#123
Renault Road
123456
"
}`

This breaks at my backend and nevertheless this payload is not identified as a valid JSON as well.

I want to make the request so that the POST data is as follow,

`{
    "id": "123456",
    "address": "#123\r\nRenault Road\r\n123456\r\n"
}`

Any help to get this done is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to send these line breaks as `\r\n` you can use some scripting to convert them back.

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the "next request" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   address = vars.get("address");
   address = address.replaceAll("\\r\\n","\\\\r\\\\n");
   vars.put("address", address);
   ```

The above script will convert line breaks to the textual representation.

References:

- `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables
- [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - is the method of String class which comes out of box with Java SDK
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - guide demonstrating how to use Java and JMeter APIs using Beanshell test elements to enhance your JMeter tests with scripting if required